# Update React Router 4 from outside react

Tags: react-router

I have a react app using React-Router **v4**.  Outside of my app I have some links that need to update the router.  How do I access the router from outside of react?  Do i expose the BrowserRouter instance on the window object somehow ?

Comment: By update, do you mean that you need to navigate from outside of your components?

Comment: Yes.  My temporary solution was when the App mounts, expose a method on the window that calls `this.context.router.transitionTo()`.  Isn't ideal but works for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** There isn't a good solution currently and you should probably wait until v4's API is finalized before you go about implementing something. There are different approaches to how you would do this for different branches/releases of the project. Which will work in the final release would mostly be a guess right now.

The ideal way would be similar to v2/3. In those versions, a `browserHistory` and `hashHistory` are made available to you, which you can import throughout your project and always have access to the same `history` instance.

You can create your own history instance in a similar way.

```
// history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

// configure your history instance here if you need to
export default createBrowserHistory()
```

Throughout your project, you would be able to import your `history` instance.

```
import history from './history'

history.push('/some-location')
```

Unfortunately, all of the router components exposed by the current versions of v4 do not allow you to pass in an existing history instance. Instead, they all create a `history` instance for you. To get around this, you would need to create your own router component that would take your `history` instance as a prop. How you would do this is completely different across the different versions.